# Conditional on a context_processor not working

Tags: python, django

I have the following piece of coding on a context proccesor file:

```
  def current_program_dj(request):
        now = tz.now()
        dj = ""

        if tz.localtime(now).weekday == 5:
            dj = "Option 1"
        elif tz.localtime(now).weekday == 6:
            dj = "Option 2"
        else:
            dj = "Option 3"

        return {
            'name_dj': dj 
  }
```

But every time I run the code it returns "Option 3" (today being Saturday). Can anyone tell me what is potentially wrong with this code?

EDIT: In a test I returned this code and it correctly returns the number 5 :) now I understand a bit less.

```
return {
            'name_dj': tz.localtime(now).weekday 
  }
```

Comment: What's the output of `print(tz.localtime(now).weekday)` for today?

Comment: And also the output of `print(type(tz.localtime(now).weekday))`

Comment: Thanks for those to comments, i realized i was getting the object and not the value, i needed to add the parenthesis tz.localtime(now).weekday()

Comment: No worries at all. Glad I could slightly help. :)